# I want to real-time plot without delay

Tags: c#, plot, uwp, windows-10

My goal is to plot real-time Line Graph using UWP(Windows10).

I use Oxyplot as Graph plotting library.
Having stacked the data I want to plot on this graph until the number of the data is up to 500,After that,The Graph start moving for the right to the left.

I want to know how to real-time plot with sliding smoothly.
My Graph sliding right to left repeats stopping and moving.

After I have run my plotting code for 20 seconds,The Graph moving speed is getting slow down, and finally,Graph moving stopped temporarily about 1 second and start moving for 3 seconds and stopped about 1 second, Repeat These moving and stopping.

I want real-time plot not to delay for the sliding for right to the left. Keeping smooth sliding Graph is my ideal.But I cant.

I have given this Graph constant value.I keep running graph plotting in another thread(task.run(() => Graph()) ). While keep plotting,GC always works in my visual studio.

Does this automatically GC cause the delay for sliding? or The cost of computation causes this delay?

Would you tell me the cause of sliding delay and how to plot smoothly?

```
public Plot_Graph()
{

    this.InitializeComponent();

    //Initialize Graph settings  
    var newMyModel = new PlotModel { Title = "Example 1" };
    MyModel = newMyModel;
    MyModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Minimum = 0.0, Maximum = 300.0, Title = "X_axis" });
    MyModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, Minimum = 0.0, Maximum = 5000.0, Title = "Y_axis" });
    line = new LineSeries();
    line.Color = OxyColors.Blue;
    MyModel.Series.Add(line);

    //Start Plotting
    Task.Run(() => Graph());

}


private int cnt = 0;
private async Task Graph()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //calculate start time.
        var start_time = long.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff"));

        //this is the Graph value. I set the value as 1000.
        int number = 1000;
        line.Points.Add(new DataPoint(cnt, number));


        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            //Here is the code to show the graph on the UI.
            GraphPloting.Model = MyModel;          
        });



        if (line.Points.Count > 500)
        {
            //If the number of the graph value is up to 500,It starts moving the Graph right to left.
            MyModel.Axes.Clear(); 
            MyModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Minimum = cnt - 500, Maximum = (cnt - 500) + 500 }); //setting of x axis.                                                                                                                                   

        }
        else
        {
            //Graph does not moving slide until the number of data becomes 500.
            MyModel.Axes.Clear(); 
            MyModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom, Minimum = 0.0, Maximum = cnt }); //settings of x axis                                                                                                            

        }

        if (line.Points.Count > 500)      
        {
            //delete the value which is out of the x axis.
            line.Points.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        //increase the value of x axis.
        cnt += 1;

        //calculate finish time.
        var end_time = long.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff"));

        //I saw these different time between start and end increase gradually.
        Debug.WriteLine("Difference_time: " + (end_time - start_time));

        //Update the graph after changing graph values.
        MyModel.InvalidatePlot(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: To recreate axes isn't an efficient way to update them. To convert a date to string and then parse it back is not an efficient way to have the number of milliseconds. To repeat that code in a tight `while` loop can possibly create million points each second (causing a full refresh EVERY NOW AND THEN).

Comment: Try this one https://github.com/royben/RealTimeGraphX